# IE 9 Scrolling when Filter are used

Tags: css

I am getting jerky & slow scrolling  when using filter: flipv fliph; or any rotation  filter

```
.verticalText{
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
  vertical-align:middle;
  cursor:default;
  writing-mode: tb-rl;
  filter: flipv fliph;
  word-break:break-all; 
  word-wrap:break-word; 
  /* IE */
  white-space: pre-wrap; 
  /* css-3 */
  white-space: -moz-pre-wrap !important; 
  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
  white-space: -pre-wrap; 
  /* Opera 4-6 */
  white-space: -o-pre-wrap; 
  /* Opera 7 */
  white-space: pre;
  white-space: pre-line;
  overflow:hidden;
  height:181px;
}
```

please help me out.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and format your question properly.